# cURL getting 403 response for IIS site

Tags: php, wordpress, iis, curl

I have a several websites running on the same IIS (7) server. One of the sites (WordPress install) has a plug-in that requires curl functionality, specifically to make use of the MailChimp API.

When I test, in the console, `curl http://myprimarysite.com` I receive a successful response. However, when I test the site in question with `curl http://mysecondarysite.com`, I receive a 403 response. Both sites are served by the same php.ini file and curl is enabled. I'm not sure what permissions I would need to add or where. Any suggestions with where to start?

Here's the response:

```
curl : error 403
We're sorry, but we could not filfill your request for / on this server.
```

I'm making some assumptions that it's got to do with bindings. Permissions all look the same, and all other sites respond with a 200.

Answer (score 0):

Check your webserver configuration (.htaccess on apache, nginx.conf on nginx), looks like you are not allowed access to `mysecondarysite.com` by IP.

Comment: No .htaccess or .conf files as it's an IIS environment.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a redirection plug-in causing the issue. Disable that plug-in, curl works just fine. Now to figure out what to do about the redirects as those aren't optional for us.